# Connection script

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Here is my connection script. I have a form on another page which brings the username and password of the user. I don't get why it always says wrong password or username.

```
 <?php
 include('functions.php');//*functions = working

  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pass_hash = md5($_POST['pass']);
  $bdd = connPDO();

  connPDO();//*DB connection functions = working
  $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Id FROM users WHERE pseudo = :user AND pass =     
  :pass');
  $req->execute(array(
  'user' => $user,
  'pass' => $pass_hash));

 $result = $req->fetch();

 if (!$result)
 {
  echo 'Wrong username or password !';
 }
 else
 {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id'] = $resultat['id'];
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
  echo 'You have successfully logged in !';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked database manually?

Comment: What happens if you do this? `$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Id FROM users WHERE pseudo = :user');`

Comment: He means did you run that select statement directly against the database, not through the PHP.

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\codeworld\loggedin.php on line 12

Comment: no I ran the select statement with php

Comment: To get rid of that error change the binding parameters.  `$req->execute(array(
  'user' => $user));`

Comment: sidenote: You should first start the session, then the rest of your code If anything errors out, you'll get an output before header warning.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: plus, you're mixing 1991 technology using MD5, *why?* there is a very simple solution to this problem. You just need to look for it.

Comment: *I'm bailing out of this one Sam* - @JayBlanchard The solution is so simple.

Comment: *My parachute is on too Ralph. Geronimo!!!!!!!!* See you on the ground @Fred-ii-

Comment: *That's a big 10-4 there Sam!* - @JayBlanchard - Hoping for a soft landing. Let's just hope it's not a soft "cactus". That would be "wiley".

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `:` in the parameters:

```
  $req->execute(array(
  ':user' => $user,
   ^----here
  ':pass' => $pass_hash));
   ^----here
```

Comment: Marc; you know those are optional and an undocumented feature. They're only required in the initial query.